# Expo Auth error on android & web; got unmatched route page could not be found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

Expo Auth error on android & web; got unmatched route page could not be found

in my code in _layout.tsx , I used this way to got token

```
const CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY;

const tokenCache = {
  async getToken(key: string) {
    try {
      return SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  },
  async saveToken(key: string, value: string) {
    try {
      return SecureStore.setItemAsync(key, value);
    } catch (err) {
      return;
    }
  },
};
```

And the expo route

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

 return (
  <ClerkProvider publishableKey={CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY!}  tokenCache={tokenCache}>
    <RootLayoutNav />;
  </ClerkProvider>
  );
```

RootLayoutNav code;

```
function RootLayoutNav() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { isLoaded, isSignedIn} = useAuth();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded && !isSignedIn){
      router.push('/(modals)/login');
    }
  }, [isLoaded]);
```

When I tried to used google & facebook account to login, I got unmatched route page could not be found.

[image]

login.tsx code

```
enum Strategy {
  Google = 'oauth_google',
  Apple = 'oauth_apple',
  Facebook = 'oauth_facebook',
}
const Page = () => {
  useWarmUpBrowser();

  const router = useRouter();
  const { startOAuthFlow: googleAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_google' });
  const { startOAuthFlow: appleAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_apple' });
  const { startOAuthFlow: facebookAuth } = useOAuth({ strategy: 'oauth_facebook' });

  const onSelectAuth = async (strategy: Strategy) => {
    const selectedAuth = {
      [Strategy.Google]: googleAuth,
      [Strategy.Apple]: appleAuth,
      [Strategy.Facebook]: facebookAuth,
    }[strategy];

    try {
      const { createdSessionId, setActive } = await selectedAuth();

      if (createdSessionId) {
        setActive!({ session: createdSessionId });
        router.back();
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('OAuth error', err);
    }
  };
```

When I running this code, I dont know why I cannot see the log in my terimal

Answer (score 0):

SDK issue I guess. Tried restarting or reinstalling.